# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on Inline JS. JS script breaks on browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, litespeed

I am facing an issue that has baffled and actually exhausted me for hours.
I have tried so many different things, have done and still doing various debugging techniques but I am very tired and would seek for some help of any kind.

I will post the very basics for start, in case someone has any helpful idea/suggestion to unstack me, and I might be adding further information or more code as we go if needed.

I am working on a Joomla site and on a custom component view I place an inline jQuery script at some point of my html output.

The problem is that while everything works well on my localhost, when I upload it online the javascript breaks in whatever point I try to create variables that contain html. Then the browser will auto-close the script tag with `</script>` and the rest of the js code will be output as html.

So for example, the following script:

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var loader = '<div id="loader"><div>';
        
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

will end up to something like below:

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var loader = '<div id="loader">';
        </div></script>

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

*Another clue that I just got is that the issue seems to be when I upload this on Litespeed server.
I tested this on 2 different servers with Litespeed and then on 1 Apache.
The one on the Apache server works fine (like on my localhost).

This is my complete inline script, just in case anyone is in place to catch anything that I am missing.

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
    var obj = <?php echo json_encode($availableTags); ?>;
    var searchForm = $('#adminForm');
    var predefinedTags = $('.tags-cloud.popular-tags .li-item');
    var searchTermId = '';
    var oldSearchTermId = '';
    var categories = <?php echo json_encode( $search_categories ); ?>;
    var categoriesAction = '<?php echo (int)$sel_categories_option; ?>';
    var list_limit = '<?php echo (int)$list_limit; ?>';
    var list_limitstart = 0;
    var list_order_by = '<?php echo $list_order_by; ?>';
    var list_order_dir = '<?php echo $list_order_dir; ?>';
    var menuItem = '<?php echo (int)$menuItem; ?>';

    var show_image = '<?php echo (int)$show_image; ?>';
    var show_date = '<?php echo (int)$show_date; ?>';
    var which_date = '<?php echo $which_date; ?>';
    var show_category = '<?php echo (int)$show_category; ?>';
    var searchResults;
    var loadMore = false;
    var loader = "";

    // Form submit
    $(searchForm).on('submit', function(e) {
      searchTermId = $('#sm-search-term-id').val();
      e.preventDefault();
      ajaxSearchArticles();
    });

    $('.search-order-selects').on('change', function(e) {
      searchTermId = $('#sm-search-term-id').val();
      list_order_by = $('#search-order').val();
      list_order_dir = $('#search-order-dir').val();
      list_limitstart = 0;
      ajaxSearchArticles();
    });

    $(predefinedTags).on('click', function(e) {
      searchTermId = $(this).attr('data-tagid');
      $( "#sm-search" ).val( $(this).text() );
      $( "#sm-search-term-id" ).val( searchTermId );
      $( "#sm-search-description" ).html( '(' + $(this).attr('total_articles') + ' Total Articles)');
      ajaxSearchArticles();
      return false;
    });

    $('#search-results').on('click','#load-more-div', function() {
      searchTermId = $('#sm-search-term-id').val();
      list_limitstart = parseInt(list_limitstart) + parseInt(list_limit);
      loadMore = true;
      ajaxSearchArticles();
    });

    function appendResults() {
      var html = '';
      oldSearchTermId = searchTermId;
      var l = parseInt(list_limit);
      $(searchResults).each(function(i, e) {
        var itemi = list_limitstart + i;
        if (i < l) {
          html += '<div id="artid-'+e.id+'" class="sm-search-result g-block s-item-'+itemi+'">';
          html += '<div class="sm-search-result-content">';

          if (show_image == '1') {
            html += '<a href="'+ e.url +'" title="'+e.title+'" target="_blank">';
            html += '<div class="smrc-image-holder"><img src="' + e.images + '" alt="'+e.title+'" /></div></a>';
          }
          html += '<div class="smrc-text-block"><a href="'+ e.url +'" title="'+e.title+'" target="_blank"><h3>'+e.title+'</h3></a><p>'+e.introtext+'</p>';
          if (show_date || show_category) {
            html += '<div class="item-meta">';
            if (show_date) {
              var date = e.modified;
              if (which_date === 'created') {
                var date = e.created;
              }
              html += '<span class="item-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+ date +'</span>';
            }
            if (show_category) {
              html += '<span class="item-cat">in '+e.category +'</span>';
            }
            html += '</div>';
          }

          html += '</div></div></div>';
        }
        if (i === l) {
          html += '<div id="load-more-div" class="sm-search-result load-more g-block">';
          html += '<div class="sm-search-result-content" style="display: flex;align-items: flex-end;justify-content: center;height: 100%;">';
          html += '<div class="load-more-results flex-item"><span>Load More...</span></div>';
          html += '</div></div>';
        }
      });
      html += '<div class="clear clearfix"></div>';
      if (loadMore) {
        $('#search-results').append(html);
      } else {
        $('#search-results').html(html);
      }

      loadMore = false;
    }

    // Autocomplete
    $( function() {
      var results = true;
      $( "#sm-search" ).autocomplete({
       minLength: 3,
       source: obj,
       focus: function( event, ui ) {
         if (results) {
          $( "#sm-search" ).val( ui.item.label );
         }
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
       },
       select: function( event, ui ) {
         if (results) {
           $( "#sm-search" ).val( ui.item.label );
           $( "#sm-search-term-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
           $( "#sm-search-description" ).html( '(' + ui.item.total_articles + ' Total Articles)');
         }
         event.preventDefault();
         $(searchForm).submit();
         return false;
       },
       response: function(event, ui) {
          if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            results = false;
            var res = { label: "no results", value: 0 };
            ui.content.push(res);
          } else {
            results = true;
          }
        }
     }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
       if (results) {
        return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<div><strong>" + capitalizeFirstLetter(item.label) + "</strong> <small>(" + item.total_articles + " articles)</small></div>" )
          .appendTo( ul );
        } else {
          return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<div>" + item.label + "</div>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        }
      };
    });


    // Ajax call
    function ajaxSearchArticles() {
      if (!searchTermId) {
        $('#empty-message').text('No Tags Defined!');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#empty-message').text('');
        }, 3000);
        return false;
      }
      $('body').append(loader);
      if (searchTermId !== oldSearchTermId) {
        list_limitstart = 0;
      }
      var xhrRequest = {
        'option'    : 'com_rabattdatabase',
        'task'      : 'RabattAjax.ajaxReceiver',
        'action'    : 'customSearch',
        'tagid'   : searchTermId,
        'orderby' : list_order_by,
        'orderdir': list_order_dir,
        'limit'   : list_limit,
        'limitstart'   : list_limitstart,
        'cats'    : categories,
        'itemid'  : menuItem,
        'catswhat': categoriesAction,
        '<?php echo JSession::getFormToken();?>' : 1,
      };

      $.ajax({
        context : this,
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : xhrRequest,
        success : function(response) {
          var response = $.parseJSON(response);
          searchResults = response.data;
          if (response.success == true) {
            appendResults();
          } else {
            $('#search-results').html("<h4>We couldn't process your request!</h4>");
          }
        }
      }); // End Ajax
    }

    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: "Then the browser will auto-close the script tag with </script>" I don't think browsers do that. What is the actual source? It's either the code doing it or some sort of CI type function changing it.

Comment: I hear ya. So, same code, only different environments. PHP Short tag settings? Are the PHP Versions different? Different OS? What differs?

Comment: Have you tried using template literals?

Comment: @Periplo - yes initially it was written with literals - there was another issue with that (can't recall it exactly to spell it right now and I eliminate them.

Comment: @ficuscr it's a mix of environments... localhost and the litespeed tests are on 7.2, the online apache is 7.1 short_open_tag is on in all except localhost, Centos is the OS of the online machines not sure about the exact version... MariaDB is the database on the litespeed, MySQL is the one in localhost and Apache... Give me a moment, I will post a link also to the broken one.

Comment: Would hope you have logs tell you if there are warnings or errors. I'm focused on why it works in one place but not another... https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php

Comment: *"I feel your pain," of course we all do.*  But – I, too, have never known a browser to "auto-close" anything.  Look very carefully at the browser output, the console, for **any** JS error-messages that you might have overlooked.  Also – as a general observation – several of your subroutines might be an excellent use-case for templating.  Good luck. // Also:  do you have any colleagues who you could ask for "the fifteen-minute rule?"  I myself just asked a co-worker to help me with something (unrelated) that had been side-tracking me for days, and *he* very quickly found it. *("D'oh!")*

Comment: Thanks @MikeRobinson - Sadly, I don't have that colleague that could help me... I have wished for this so many times, because I know that sometimes another pair of eyes, a whole new perspective, is all that is needed. Usually, I do this alone, so I have to take a break and go away of the problem, to come later refreshed. Then the solution is easier. By the way, I have started reaching somewhere and it looks like the issue is not related with my code, but another 3rd party plugin conflicts and produces that issue. I am gonna leave it for today, and come back tomorrow to fix it.

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.